# moving compare products block to the bottom of right side

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, local.xml

The compare products block currently appears at the top of right column. I want it to be at the bottom of the right column. How can I do this in my local.xml. I also want my cart to be at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered pretty good in a post here. It explains pretty well about putting blocks in a certain order.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410206/change-order-of-blocks-via-local-xml-file-in-magento

Comment: Curious if there is a benefit to using the method provided in the SO question over using the standard `<block>` declaration.